# On which basis Adi Shankaracharya was considered shivavtar?

Tags: shiva, vedanta, adi-shankaracharya

What is the reference of consider bhagwatpad Adi Shankaracharya to be an incarnation of shiva ? Did he proclaimed himself to be so anywhere ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, many Puranas mention Adi Shankara to be an incarnation of Shiva.

Lord Shiva in the Padma Purana, Uttara Khanda, Chapter 236 states:

> *mayavadam asac chastram pracchannam bauddham uchyate mayaiva kalpitam devi kalau brahmana rupina* (Padma Purana 6.236.7)
>
> **Translation**: "Mayavada or Advaita philosophy is an impious, wicked belief and against all the conclusions of the Vedas. It is only covered Buddhism. My dear Parvati, in Kali-Yoga **I assume the form of a brahmana (Adi Shankara)** and teach this imagined philosophy.

In the 30th chapter of the Kurma Purana too, Adi Shankaracharya is mentioned an incarnation of Shiva:

> तदेव साधयेन्नृणां देवतानां च दैवतम्। करिष्यत्यवताराणि शंकरो नीललोहितः॥३३॥
>
> श्रीतस्मार्तप्रतिष्ठार्थ भक्तानां हितकाम्यया। उपदेक्ष्यंति
>   तज्ज्ञानं शिष्याणां ब्रह्मसंज्ञितम्॥ ३४॥
>
> सर्ववेदान्तसारं हि
>   धर्मान्वेदनिदर्शितान्। सर्ववर्णान् समुद्दिश्य स्वधर्मा ये निदर्शिताः।।३५।।
>
> **Translation**: The people should adore Lord Mahadeva, who happens to be the god of
>   gods. **The brown complexioned Shiva, for the establishment of Srauta**
>   **(Vedic) and Smarta dharmas (belonging to the Smritis), and for the**
>   **welfare of the devotees shall incarnate on earth. He will enlighten**
>   **his devotees on the subjects of the gist of Vedantas, the knowledge**
>   **relating to the Brahman, and all the dharmas enshrined in the Vedas**,
>   which have been narrated earlier.

Comment: Hi, thanks but these are indirect references. How can anyone conclude that this is about Adi Shankaracharya only ?

Comment: It talks explicitly about a preacher of Advaita philosophy or Smarta Dharma which points to Adi Shankaracharya. @user19357

Comment: @Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury First reference talks of mAyavAda. Now whether this is a reference to advaita, how do we know? Second reference is generic. Who knows whom it refers to? By the way, I think both references are post-Shankaran, but trying to argue from an insider perspective.